# Why do I get "undefined array key" when trying to get values from HTML forms?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have attached the code samples of my html and php files along with the error I'm getting whenever I try to
run the code to get values entered in my html form to my php document.
I'm using the XAMPP server.

I have done this exactly as mentioned in the site  mentioned below:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

I would really appreciate it of someone could help me out with this.

HTML SAMPLE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="POST">

 Name : <input type="text" name="name"> <br><br>
 E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br> <br>
 <input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>

 PHP SAMPLE:

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

Hello <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
Your email address is <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

ERROR in my browser:

Warning: Undefined array key "name" in
C:\xampp\htdocs\BasicIntro\welcome.php on line 5
Your email address is

Warning: Undefined array key "email" in
C:\xampp\htdocs\BasicIntro\welcome.php on line 6

Comment: the PHP code was still missing?

Comment: Are you sure there are $_POST[] and not $_GET[] in welcome.php?

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, do you get those errors when submitting the form (clicking the button) or are you accessing the `welcome.php` page directly (which is where I assume you have that PHP code?) Is the form and the PHP in two different pages?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My php code and form are in two different files. When  I submit the form , the form page shows my php code. The welcome.php page is having that error without me clicking submit

Comment: @MichelaDurazzi I get the same error even when I use $_GET

Comment: Well, if it's not a POST request (that is, you haven't hit "submit" but just opened the page), then the `$_POST[]` array will be empty, of course.

Comment: @MichelaDurazzi When I fill my form and click submit, it automatically  turns into my welcome.php page(shows my php code). And the error in the original php page stays the same

Comment: @MichelaDurazzi I sent the same files to a friend of mine and it's working fine for them. Do you think the problem is my server?

Comment: @coder, if you add this in your welcome.php, what happens?
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>

Comment: @MichelaDurazzi My form page turns into welcome.php displaying my php code (After I click "submit") . The original php page displays this: Array()

Comment: @coder you must click on submit, if you call welcome.php without passing params it is obvious that it does not work.
If you see php code on browser then your web server (apache?) it isn't well configured.

Comment: @MichelaDurazzi My problem was with the installation and I re installed XAMPP. My code is working now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both pages are working. no mistakes. I dont know why it does not work for you.
Try reinstalling XAMPP.

Comment: I did and it's working now. Thank you for helping :)